# How set default output type to JSON ins DSS

Tags: json, wso2, wso2-data-services-server

We have a mobile app using Restkit which would use as WSO2 DSS service as the backend of the app. The service has a database data source. However the developer is complaining that he gets an error that the service is only returning text/plain format. The service has a JSON output type and mapped on a json format. He said that in reskit it does not send the sevice the header content type but it is expecting a json output format. Is there anyway I can set DSS default output type as json output. I've already tried all the solutions in the net but still getting same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally JSON return handled by httpContentNegotiation parameter on  'axis2.xml' and in 'axis2_client.xml'.

```
  <parameter name="httpContentNegotiation">true</parameter>
```

So simply you can set content request header with

```
   Accept:application/json
```

ex:

```
 curl -v -H "Accept:application/json" 'your_path'
```

Comment: I already told the developer that the solution was that. I even showed them the articles and documentation but they are insisting that Restkit has no way to tell the service that it wants a json formatted output. They are telling that the service should ouput a default json format

Answer (score 1):

If you are using restkit make sure to add a custom header to http request. You need to set the Accept header as mentioned above. Please find this [link](http://restkit-tutorials.com/restkit-how-to-set-custom-header-for-http-request/).